# How to install a single package from Debian sid?

Tags: debian, aptitude, package-management

Take ibus-sunpinyin for example, which isn't existed in the squeeze release. I'm not going to switch the whole system to the sid branch, so, I want to download the single package from sid repository and install it like:

```
# Add the sid repository
sudo mv /tmp/sid.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

# Error: can't install because version conflicts of libc6:
#     sudo apt-get install ibus-sunpinyin

# This is ok but it will upgrade a lot of mess from sid branch:
#     sudo apt-get upgrade ibus-sunpinyin

# So, instead of apt-get install/upgrade, let me download & install the single package.
# However, this errored again because of version conflicts of libc6:
#      apt-get install --download-only ibus-sunpinyin

## THEN, WHAT CAN I DO? ##

# Remove the sid repository.
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sid.list /tmp

# Install the single package.
sudo dpkg -i ./ibus-sunpinyin-x.x.x.deb
```

Comment: To download a single package: you can `apt-get download ...` (for apt-get 0.8.11+), or `aptitude download ...`. However, I'm also failed to `sudo dpkg -i ibus-sunpinyin-x.x.x.deb` due to sid dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try downloading the source packages from the sid repository, and build them on your squeeze system.  You might run into trouble if there are a lot of dependencies, or if the package depends on a version of a library that is not available in squeeze.

If this works, then you don't need to maintain another distribution in a separate folder, as you would with the bootstrapped approach.

Comment: apt-pinning is the proper way to do this, TBH. http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html

Answer (score 15):

What you REALLY want is to learn about apt-pinning. http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html

Comment: You need this if the package you want has no backport. Otherwise I would wager backports generally function better.

Comment: Yeah. Backports are a much safer bet. Apt-pinning will not always work and will sometimes pull way more than you want (nobody will want to help if you pull libc6 from sid!)

Answer (score 5):

One easy way to do this is to set preferences so that the system uses `stable` for most packages but falls back to `testing` or `unstable` for missing packages.

Here are the steps:

1. Add this to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main non-free contrib
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main non-free contrib
   ```
2. Write this to `/etc/apt/preferences` (or create the file)

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release a=stable
   Pin-Priority: 700

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=testing
   Pin-Priority: 650

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=unstable
   Pin-Priority: 600
   ```
3. Run `apt-get update`
4. Install the package you want (e.g. `apt-get install ibus-sunpinyin`)

PS: You can force the installation of an *unstable* package with `apt-get install <package>/unstable`

Comment: this marks 18 packages as updateable for me, meaning the priorities seem to be ignored...

Comment: A bit late to the party @xeruf, but it doesn't work copying the above example as it adds a white space first in each line. You need to delete that space for it to work. Apt will mention nothing about it and just pretend like all is fine, except no pins applied. Using `apt-cache policy` will show the prios for different releases and your sources

Answer (score 4):

This package is available in [Debian Backports](http://backports.debian.org/), which will make your life a lot easier.  These are generally packages pulled from testing or unstable (sid), and "backported" to the current stable release.

Add this line to your `sources.list`

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main
```

then run:

```
apt-get update && apt-get -t squeeze-backports install ibus-sunpinyin
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around this is to use `cdebootstrap` to install a basic sid system, then use `chroot` to run the program you need within the new system.

`cdebootstrap` installs a new debian system from whichever distribution you want in a directory. Then, `chroot` lets you run programs in that other distribution without rebooting or anything.

You can also use `mount --bind` to let the chrooted system access your home folder, /proc, etc.

From within the chrooted system, apt-get will install from the sid repository.

For a more detailed explanation, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot.